# What is the difference between "pom" type dependency with scope "import" and without "import"?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

Starting from Maven 2.0.9 there is possibility to include

```
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
```

in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

As I understand it, it will be "replaced" with dependencies included in this pom as if they were originally defined here.

What is the difference between solution above and simple dependency to this pom without `import` scope (I saw the latter being called "dependencies grouping")? Is the only difference that such "grouped" dependencies have lower priority while resolving dependencies precedence?

Answer (score 239, accepted):

You can only import *managed dependencies*.  This means you can only *import* other POMs into the `dependencyManagement` section of your project's POM. i.e.

```xml
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>other.pom.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>other-pom-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
```

What then happens is that all the dependencies defined in the `dependencyManagement` section of the `other-pom-artifact-id` are included in your POM's `dependencyManagement` section. You can then reference these dependencies in the `dependency` section of your POM (and all of its child POMs) without having to include a `version` etc.

However if in your POM you simply define a normal dependency to `other-pom-artifact-id` then all `dependencies` from the `dependency` section of the `other-pom-artifact-id` are included transitively in your project - however the dependencies defined in the `dependencyManagement` section of the `other-pom-artifact-id` are not included at all.

So basically the two different mechanisms are used for importing/including the two different types of dependencies (managed dependencies and normal dependencies).

There is a good page on the maven website, which can explain this far better than I can, [Dependency Management in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management) and it also contains specific information on [importing dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies).

Comment: great answer to explain how it works, but why?? why you don't want include the other dependencies transitively? also can you do both? import other-pom-artifact-id and then declare other-pom-artifact-id as dependency as well?

Comment: One article on DZone states something different: `...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>pomlib-lib</artifactId>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>pomlib-war</artifactId>
      <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>`[DRY and Skinny War](https://dzone.com/articles/dry-and-skinny-war)

Comment: @JunchenLiu : So lets say you are using only a couple of features of project A, so you can choose to include only those transitive dependencies which are required for that feature. You can work that out by using <exclude> in <dependency> also.
For example checkout this : http://jdbi.org/#_getting_started

Comment: @DB5 That maven link explaining different scenarios is confusing AF. But thank you.

Answer (score 21):

You cannot have a `pom` type project as a `simple dependency` in another project.  (Well, you can - but it will not do anything useful).  There can only be a `parent-child` relationship.  This is essentially `managing dependency through inheritance`.

`import` scope for `pom` type dependency in `<dependencyManagement>` section allows you to achieve the equivalent of `multiple inheritance`.

You could have different `poms` - each `managing` a bunch of related dependencies.  The projects which use these could `import` these `poms` and then specify the dependencies that they need without needing to worry about the version.  This is essentially the `bill of materials` concept, which is illustrated in the links specified by @DB5.

This helps to keep `parent poms` of complex multi-module projects from getting too large and unwieldy.

Comment: Are you sure? I've put regular pom (having its own dependencies) as a regular dependency in other project (packaging war) and got all the dependencies from pom project included in WEB-INF/lib of target project. That's why I'm asking this question :)

Comment: Thanks @Raghuram, totally forgot to mention the parent POM option when answering the question. As for having a pom type project as a simple dependency this is possible. As mentioned in the original question it can be used to [group dependencies](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html)

Comment: [Working link about group dependencies](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps)

Answer (score 12):

Two concepts, very much similar to object-oriented programming paradigm, will help to answer the question:

1. The **dependencyManagement** section only declares the dependencies and their details in the current project - the purpose is management of the details and re-use in other projects, either via inheritance (***parent***) or import (***scope***).  This is like declaring a data type in program and make it available for use.
2. The ***dependency*** section defines the actual use of the dependencies in the project, optionally inherit the details (i.e., version, etc.) of the dependencies declared under the ***dependencyManagment***. That's why you will have missing dependencies if you only put them in ***dependencyManagment***. This is analogous to instantiating an variable instance of a data type in a program where it is needed.

Comment: That's good and clear but it answers a different question from the one above. :-)