# What are the group and artifact names for individual ImageJ2 libraries through Maven?

Tags: maven, imagej

I've spent most of yesterday trying to figure out what to use in my pom.xml file so I can get the ImageJ2 libraries that I need **without inheriting from the ImageJ parent pom**. I figured out the following settings, but they are far from optimal:

```
    ...
    <repository>
        <id>imagej.public</id>
        <url>http://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
        <artifactId>imagej</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-rc-28</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

The problem I have is that it appears that **all** of ImageJ2 is downloaded this way. There is a massive dependency tree and some 60+ jar files are now in my classpath in eclipse.

How can I pick and choose the individual libraries that I need, and which one of them is the base version (like ij.jar was for ImageJ1)? And how can I find the available version number(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> all of ImageJ2 is downloaded this way.

`net.imagej:imagej` is indeed the application-level project that aggregates all the ImageJ2 components.

> How can I pick and choose the individual libraries that I need
>   And how can I find the available version number(s)?

All components of ImageJ2 are Mavenized and can be consumed directly/independently, the same way you included `net.imagej:imagej`. There are several ways to browse the components and available versions - for example:

- Browse components on GitHub. The [source code](http://imagej.net/Source_code) is divided into projects across several organizations. Each project will have its own pom (e.g. [imagej-common](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-common/blob/master/pom.xml)) and [list of releases](https://github.com/imagej/imagej-common/releases).
- Look at [the BOMs](http://imagej.net/BOM#Maven_component_structure) for each project. For example, [pom-imagej](https://github.com/imagej/pom-imagej/tree/pom-imagej-7.0.0) will give you the list of ImageJ components at versions that work together.
- Search Maven central (not all projects hosted here - search by groupId, e.g. [net.imagej](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cnet.imagej), [io.scif](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cio.scif), [org.scijava](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.scijava))
- Search the [ImageJ nexus](http://maven.imagej.net/)

> without inheriting from the ImageJ parent pom.

Even if you don't declare `pom-imagej` as a parent pom, if you end up using multiple ImageJ components you would benefit from [scope:import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778276/difference-between-scope-import-and-pom-type-dependency)ing it (or another appropriate BOM). Leaning on BOM dependency management will help ensure your components are at versions that work well together.

> which one of them is the base version (like ij.jar was for ImageJ1)

It really depends on what you are trying to develop. The ImageJ wiki gives an [overview of how functionality is divided](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) in ImageJ2. There is also a comprehensive [development section](http://imagej.net/Development).

For more technical questions about ImageJ2 development, you may also want to try the [ImageJ-devel mailing list](http://imagej.net/mailman/listinfo/imagej-devel).

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I only started using Maven yesterday explicitly for ImageJ so I'm still learning quite a bit about it. Where can I find out more about scope:import?

Comment: [Maven BOMs](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/02/18/maven-bom-bill-of-materials-dependency/) and [managed dependency imports](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVEN/Importing+Managed+Dependencies) are a couple pages that give good examples of when to use scope:import. If you aren't extending another POM, though, it may make more sense to just extend [pom-imagej](https://github.com/imagej/pom-imagej/tree/pom-imagej-7.0.0)