# package com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-cloud

I am building the code `"tollrate-billboard"` which has following dependencies. When I am trying to build the code `> mvn clean install -DskipTests`, getting the below error.

Also, `HystrixCommand` is already part of the `hystrix-javanica-1.5.12.jar`, so still compiler complaining about the same.

Could anyone please guide what is the issue ?

Error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project tollrate-billboard: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Not_working/tollrate-billboard/src/main/java/pluralsight/demo/DashboardController.java:[13,55] package com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Not_working/tollrate-billboard/src/main/java/pluralsight/demo/DashboardController.java:[28,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class HystrixCommand
[ERROR]   location: class pluralsight.demo.DashboardController
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project tollrate-billboard: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1161)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

**DashboardController.java**

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand;
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "getTollRateBackup")
    @RequestMapping("/dashboard")
    public String GetTollRate(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) {

        TollRate tr = restTemplate.getForObject("http://pluralsight-toll-service/tollrate/"+ stationId, TollRate.class);
        System.out.println("stationId: " + stationId);
        m.addAttribute("rate", tr.getCurrentRate());
        return "dashboard";
    }

    public String getTollRateBackup(@RequestParam int stationId, Model m) { 
        System.out.println("Fallback operation called");
        m.addAttribute("rate", "1.00");
        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**EDIT-1:**

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starters:pom:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT @ line 67, column 16
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starters:pom:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT @ line 67, column 16

    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:382)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:400)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:391)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:511)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project pluralsight.demo:tollrate-billboard:1.0 (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Not_working\tollrate-billboard\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starters:pom:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT @ line 67, column 16 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starters:pom:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
    at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel (ProjectModelResolver.java:197)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement (DefaultModelBuilder.java:1245)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:457)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build (DefaultModelBuilder.java:423)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:580)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:372)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:400)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:391)
    at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build (DefaultGraphBuilder.java:78)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph (DefaultMaven.java:511)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:221)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following above your `<dependencies>` tag and recheck:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starters</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and also remove version tag for `spring-cloud-starter-hystrix` from the dependency you alreadt defined in your pom file as:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
      <!--   <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version> ::::REMOVE THIS LINE::::  -->  
    </dependency>
```

Comment: No, it did not work. Updated error (in EDIT-1 above post) for this dependency addition. Also I did not found any such dependency in maven central repository.

Comment: this is not a repository, in case you are interested, you could refer to :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778276/what-is-the-difference-between-scope-import-and-pom-type-dependency

Comment: @Sayali I forgot to say, please also remove version for spring-cloud-starter-hystrix dependency

Comment: @Sayali I have updated my answer, hope it makes it clear

Comment: Its still not working - if I comment out the starter hystrix version, it gives me Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:jar is missing.

Comment: that’s odd ! could you commit your code on git to see if i can help you ?

Comment: Here is my whole code: https://github.com/JavaHelper/micro-services-tutorials/tree/master/Java-MS-With-SpringCloud-Coordinating-Services/Module-4_2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: @Sayali I have just cloned and checked the code, surprisingly, it has got no problem and could build the project and generate the jar file. could you please let me know the version of java and maven in your system ?

Comment: Could you please commit changes?

Comment: @Sayali i didnt change anything, I have executed  mvn clean install -DskipTests as you did and got the jar file , it seems you have multiple java version if so make sure you are using version 8 by checking JAVA_HOME

Comment: I am using Java 8 and Maven 3.5. Are you running the tollrate-billboard ?

Comment: @Sayali that's so strange! mine is also the same.