# Dependency of Type "POM"

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to get an ESB system running using ServiceMix and ActiveMQ. But even before I get that far, I had a question about dependency types of POM. I got the maven dependency as:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix/servicemix -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.servicemix</groupId>
    <artifactId>servicemix</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Now when I run "clean install" on the the project in which I included this dependency, I don't see any of the activeMQ jars being copied in the classpath or available for compilation (I have copy-dependency written, so I can see what jar files are included). In this case, do I still have to explicitly mention the activeMQ dependency in my pom file? Like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. This ServiceMix is frustrating with the lack of documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "pom" type dependency with scope "import" and without "import"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778276/what-is-the-difference-between-pom-type-dependency-with-scope-import-and-wit)

Comment: I looked at that answer and a few other like it. I did include the dependency under `dependencyManagement` in my parent project and tried to use `import` scope in my child module, but i get the error `org.apache.servicemix:servicemix:pom must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'import'.` So that solution didn't help

Answer (score 5):

If you put a dependency of type `pom` into your `<dependencies>`, Maven will use the content of the POM as transitive dependencies. So everything in that POM will become a part of the classpath unless it has something like `test` scope or its version is overridden by some other part of the POM.

Putting a POM into the `<dependencyManagement>` is a different thing. Note that scope `import` is only for `<dependencyManagement>`.

Comment: So putting <type>pom</type> in a dependency under <dependencies> is similar to not putting it at all ? If yes then when putting it ?

Comment: @OlivierMasseau Sorry, cannot follow you. As I said: If you have e.g. a pom with three dependencies, and you put that pom as dependency in your project, then the three dependencies will become transitive dependencies of your project.

Comment: @J Fabien Meier I've detailed my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76271528/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-not-using-typepom-type-for-a-depend (which I see you answered). Thanks ;)