# What is the difference between using and not using <type>pom</type> for a dependency (in the <dependencies> section)?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I cannot really find any documentation on this. Yet I sometimes see this in the `<dependencies>` section of some pom.xml files :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

But I cannot understand the difference with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

From my knowledge `<type>pom</type>` is only relevant for dependencies found in the `<dependencyManagement>` section.

I don't understand how it can be useful in the `<dependencies>` section.

Comment: it may allow to establish build order across reactor modules

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Sounds like a bad idea. Where do you need that?

Comment: previously we were using such trick in integration tests - every module was responsible for particular action: install db, run tests, run application, etc. Later I have written ext which allows to not rebuild project/deps on each `mvn -pl ...` and that became not actual anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use case:

You always have the same five dependencies in most of your projects. But you cannot handle this through a parent POM because you e.g. already need to use a fixed parent POM.

Then you can create a project `onlypom` of type `pom` that only contains a `pom.xml` with the said five dependencies. Then you add a dependency to `onlypom` of type `pom` in your projects `<dependencies>` section, so that you can avoid to always copy/paste five dependency entries.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I've found this really good article which describes in details this use case :
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps

Answer (score 0):

You can only import managed dependencies. This means you can only import other POMs into the dependencyManagement section of your project's POM. i.e.

```
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>other.pom.group.id</groupId>
            <artifactId>other-pom-artifact-id</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
```

What then happens is that all the dependencies defined in the dependencyManagement section of the other-pom-artifact-id are included in your POM's dependencyManagement section. You can then reference these dependencies in the dependency section of your POM (and all of its child POMs) without having to include a version etc.

However if in your POM you simply define a normal dependency to other-pom-artifact-id then all dependencies from the dependency section of the other-pom-artifact-id are included transitively in your project - however the dependencies defined in the dependencyManagement section of the other-pom-artifact-id are not included at all.

So basically the two different mechanisms are used for importing/including the two different types of dependencies (managed dependencies and normal dependencies).

There is a good page on the maven website, which can explain this far better than I can, Dependency Management in Maven and it also contains specific information on importing dependencies.