# why do i have a jboss spec compile error?

Tags: java, maven

I have a empty, brand new maven project that has this single dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-8.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Full POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-8.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run the compile, I get this error:

`Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:test:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.6-RC1, org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-impl:jar:1.2.6-RC1: Failure to find org.apache.taglibs:taglibs-standard-spec:jar:1.2.6-RC1 in https://cruglobal.jfrog.io/cruglobal/maven-all was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced`

Wondering what might be going on here, and how to resolve this error?
It does not appear as the taglibs library version appears on the mvnrepository site, so wondering what i should do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this the right dependency? You added a POM as dependency, which is possible, but unsual.

Comment: I think so, i am trying to pull all the javaEE 8 dependencies.
The end goal is to have an existing javaEE 7 project upgraded to EE8, and then ported from wildfly 8 to wildly 21.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing dependencies vs. dependencyManagement. There is some good reading on the topics online so I won't repeat or muddy the waters by explaining it myself.

Here is an example SO that hits on the concepts: [What is the difference between "pom" type dependency with scope "import" and without "import"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778276/what-is-the-difference-between-pom-type-dependency-with-scope-import-and-wit)

Also, for now, try removing the "pom" to see if that will allow transitive dependencies to be retrieved.